# AppleScript - finding creation/modification dates for files

Tags: date, time, timestamp, applescript, evernote

I have simple service I'm using to import Evernote files:

on run {input}
    tell application "Evernote"
        repeat with x in input
            try
                create note from file x
            on error error_message number error_number
                display alert "Send to Evernote Failed" message "Error: " & error_message & "" & "Error Number:  " & error_number as warning
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
end run

I would like to "create note from file x created d", where d is a date/time that matches that of the original file - but I don't know how to get the date/time (either created or modified) of the original file in a format that is an applescript date.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know where you´re getting your "input" from, but assuming that with "files" you literally mean files int the Finder, calling Finder to get info on the file in "input" should work like this:

```
tell application "Finder" to set input to selection
repeat with x in input
    tell application "Finder" to set creationDate to creation date of x  
end repeat
```